# restoring chef client changes public key

Tags: chef-infra

i am trying to restore a chef client in a new chef-server (to be used as replacement chef server) using knife backup/ export tool. Looks like the client object is not being restored properly in the restore phase. The public key seems to be changed during restore in the new chef server. How to overcome this ? i want to use old clients with the new Chef server just by updating the endpoint in client.rb file. My chef version is pretty old: 10.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate validation key and update the same in the node.

Comment: Validation key was kept intact in the replacement Chef server. So is the case for clients which are live as usual. Not sure why uploading the client object to CounchDB in new chef server changes the public key ! Don't think that's expected.